# present modal view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am just getting started with iphone development
I have a Tabbed application and I wanted to display a log in form modally
so i looked here [Apple Dev](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CombiningViewControllers/CombiningViewControllers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH104-SW3)  and did this inside one of my view controllers
I connected a button to the following action:

```
 #import "LoginForm.h"
...
-(IBAction)showLogin{
LoginForm *lf = [[LoginForm alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginForm" bundle:nil];
lf.delegate = self;
lf.modalPresentationStyle =  UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[self presentModalViewController:lf animated:YES];
}
```

when I build I get "request for member 'delegate' in something not a structure or union"
If I get rid of the second line, it builds but pressing the button does nothing.

What am I missing here?

Comment: If i use the same code on a ViewBased app i get the same error on the second line, but if i remove the line the modal view appears when i press the button...do i need something special for the delegation? and for the tabbed template?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Sounds like you haven't declared a `delegate` member for LoginForm. You'll need to add code that lets the UIViewController instance that's presenting LoginForm modally when LoginForm is done. Here's how to declare your own delegate:

In LoginForm.h:

```
@class LoginForm;

@protocol LoginFormDelegate
- (void)loginFormDidFinish:(LoginForm*)loginForm;
@end

@interface LoginForm {
    // ... all your other members ...
    id<LoginFormDelegate> delegate;
}

// ... all your other methods and properties ...

@property (retain) id<LoginFormDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

In LoginForm.m:

```
@implementation

@synthesize delegate;

//... the rest of LoginForm's implementation ...

@end
```

Then in the UIViewController instance that presents LoginForm (let's call it MyViewController):

In MyViewController.h:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <LoginFormDelegate>

@end
```

In MyViewController.m:

```
/**
 * LoginFormDelegate implementation
 */
- (void)loginFormDidFinish:(LoginForm*)loginForm {
   // do whatever, then
   // hide the modal view
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
   // clean up
   [loginForm release];
}

- (IBAction)showLogin:(id)sender {
    LoginForm *lf = [[LoginForm alloc]initWithNibName:@"LoginForm" bundle:nil];
    lf.delegate = self;
    lf.modalPresentationStyle =  UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
    [self presentModalViewController:lf animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: thanks so much...this is what i was looking for.
The one last thing it's saying inside the protocol declaration is, that i can't figure out:

 "Expected ')' before LoginForm "

i dont see much wrong with it. the only difference with your code is that my form is inheriting from UIViewController, but it doesnt look like is related to that error

Comment: My bad... I forgot the `@class LoginForm;` before the protocol declaration. I've edited the source in my answer.

Comment: thanks, i also did an import in the MyViewController so that it could see the protocol, and it compiles but it still crashes before hitting the first line of the ShowLogin function

the console shows an uncaught exception 

 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIViewController showLogin]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5936080'

Comment: How are you calling `showLogin`? If it's by using a connection in Interface Builder, make sure you re-connect it now that the signature changed from `showLogin` in your original code to `showLogin:(id)sender` in the updated code.

Comment: you should also mention adding an #import statement in MyViewController.h so it knows about the delegate.

Comment: I'd like to add you're not supposed to retain a delegate!

Comment: `lf.modalPresentationStyle =  UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;`. `PresentationStyle` or `TransitionStyle`?

Comment: one more thing needs to be added to complete this code, The loginForm.m viewcontroller's closing method should call,

`[self.delegate loginFormDidFinish:self];` so it notifies the delegat that form is closing and triggers the associated loginFormDidFinish method in MyViewController.m file.

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that your `LoginForm` class derives from `UIViewController`.  The `UIViewController` class doesn't have a `delegate` property, hence the compile error you got.

Your problem is probably that the action doesn't get called in the first place.  The proper signature for an action is:

```
- (IBAction)showLogin:(id)sender;
```

The `sender` argument is required.  Put a breakpoint in your method to make sure it is called.

Comment: how do i declare the delegate for the loginForm?
and yes i think you are right i dont see the breakpoint being hit

Comment: This is incorrect. An action method can take either zero parameters or one (the control sending it), and Interface Builder will happily hook a control up to an - (IBAction)doWhatever method.