# iOS: How to have a login-form showed?

Tags: iphone, ios, view, authentication

I have the mainWindow.xib in my application with a TabController in it for my main-menu.

Now I want to have a Login-form for my application.
I added a View (LoginViewController) and show this view at beginning:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
// Override point for customization after application launch.
// Add the tab bar controller's current view as a subview of the window

self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

LoginViewController *lvc = [[LoginViewController alloc]     initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];
lvc.delegate = self;
[self.tabBarController presentModalViewController:lvc animated:false];
[lvc release];

return YES;
}
```

Next I have my login-checks in the view, okay.

Now I try to dismiss the view after this.
For this I searched around and found the question here: [present modal view controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304790/present-modal-view-controller)

I add all things to my project, but getting a error in this code:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface Animexx3AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate, 
                            UITabBarControllerDelegate, LoginViewControllerDelegate>
{
UIWindow *window;
UITabBarController *tabBarController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

Which means "cannot find protocol LoginViewControllerDelegate" in line 2/3.

Addition in the line "lvc.delegate = self" I get a warning that tells me "assigning to "id" from incompatible type "Animexx3AppDalagte".

What did Im wrong?

Comment: Please change the `false` boolean literal to `NO` that is the same literal defined for Cocoa. You will notice that your code reads better, and old time Objective-C programmers like me will not cringe when we see your code :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import the header file where you declared the `LoginViewControllerDelegate` protocol. Most likely the `LoginViewController.h` file.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling with this many times, we published an open source library called [CLHoppingViewController](https://github.com/eladb/CLHoppingViewController) which handles exactly this kind of scenarios.

So, in your case, you would do something like this to describe the start up flow:

```m
UIViewController *loginViewController;
UIViewController *mainViewController;

if (user_not_logged_in) {
  [self hopToViewController:loginViewController then:^{
    [self hopToViewController:mainViewController then:nil];
  }];
}
else {
  [self hopToViewController:mainViewController then:nil];
}
```

The library can support much more advanced conditional sequences. For example, you can display a splash screen, conditionally show onboarding UX, etc.

There's a short tutorial [here](http://hackingonstuff.net/post/78005128788).